# C++ Remove sub-strings from a vector of strings

Tags: c++, stl

Given a vector of strings:

```
    std::vector<std::string> contents {"right", "sun is shining", "high hopes", "I wish you were here", "shining", "do it right"};
```

I would like to remove all elements that are substring of others. In this example "right" and "shining" are the ones to be removed.

I m doing that looping through the vector and for each element, doing another loop to check if we have a different element containing it.
See the actual code below.

I m wondering if there is a better way to do it. (Using stl algorithm?)

```
    std::vector<std::string> contents{"right", "sun is shining",
    "high hopes", "I wish you were here", "shining", "do it right"};
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < contents.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < contents.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (i != j && boost::algorithm::contains(contents[j], contents[i]))
            {
                std::cout << "[" << contents[i] << "] contained in [" << contents[j] << "]" <<std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == contents.size())
        {
            std::cout << "[" << contents[i] << "] not contained in any element" << std::endl;
            result.push_back(contents[i]);
        }
    }
```

The expected result will be:
{"sun is shining", "high hopes", "I wish you were here","do it right"};

Comment: "Better way" in which sense? Asymptotic time complexity? Fewer lines of code?

Comment: If you need replacement for `boost::algorithm::contains()`, then `std::string::find()` should suffice. Also inner loop can be replaced with `std::find()`.

Comment: Is the order of the result important?  If not, then consider sorting the strings by length as a first step.

Comment: @BiagioFesta better way: current code is ugly: n*n complexity, a lot of code, while it s quite simple task. (It s just a feeling that the stl algorithm can do that in a better way: more readable code, and more efficient...).

Comment: @sklott, good point. +readable.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Better or not better.

I think that your solution is OK. Why you are using boost, I do not understand. It is not needed here. The task is trivial.

The compexity is always n*n (Not fully. We do not compare a string to istself)

I prepared 3 alternatives.

Version 1 is using `std::algorithm`s.

Nobody will understand it and it looks like obfuscated code.

Version 2 is completely identical with version 1. I just added many newlines and comments. People can learn from that and will probably understand it. But actually, also many statements here.

Version 3 is in my opinion the most reasonable approch. Similar to yours. Just using the range based for. And no boost. Simple C++ statements.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void version1()
{
    // Source data
    std::vector<std::string> contents{ "right", "sun is shining", "high hopes", "I wish you were here", "shining", "do it right" };
    // print filtered data to std::out 
    std::copy_if(contents.begin(), contents.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
        [&contents](std::string & s1) { return std::find_if(contents.begin(), contents.end(), [&s1](std::string & s2) {
            return (s1 != s2) && (s2.find(s1) != std::string::npos); }) == contents.end(); });

}

void version2()
{
    // Source data
    std::vector<std::string> contents{ "right", "sun is shining", "high hopes", "I wish you were here", "shining", "do it right" };

    // Copy data to standard out only if
    std::copy_if
    (
        contents.begin(),                   // Evaluate from the begin of the source string 
        contents.end(),                     // To the end of the source string
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),    // Display found results on console
        [&contents](std::string & s1)       // The lambda to decide, if we will copy or not
        {   
            return std::find_if             // We will copy only, if we do not find a substring
            (
                contents.begin(),           // We compare verything with everything
                contents.end(),             // Every word, from the source string with every other word
                [&s1](std::string & s2) 
                {
                    return (s1 != s2) &&    // But not the same string with itself
                           (s2.find(s1) != std::string::npos);  // Check, if it is a substring
                }
            ) == contents.end();            // If we cannot find a substring, then we copy the data to the output
        }
    );
}

void version3()
{
    // Source data
    std::vector<std::string> contents{ "right", "sun is shining", "high hopes", "I wish you were here", "shining", "do it right" };

    // Iterate over all strings in source vector
    for (const std::string& s1 : contents) {

        // Initially we have not found a substring
        bool subStringFound{ false };

        // Now compare every string in vector with every other string
        for (const std::string& s2 : contents) {
            // If one is a real substring of the other
            if ((s1 != s2) && (s2.find(s1) != std::string::npos)) {
                // Then we found something
                subStringFound = true;
            }
        }
        // If we did not find a substring
        if (!subStringFound)
            // Then show it
            std::cout << s1 << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n\nVersion 1\n\n";
    version1();
    std::cout << "\n\nVersion 2\n\n";
    version2();
    std::cout << "\n\nVersion 3\n\n";
    version3();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do _I_ get extra marks for saying I **understood** v1?

Comment: It is very interesting that many other people would not even recognize that version 1 and 2 are C++ code wise completely identical. There is no difference. But we can make code more readable by good formatting and better understandable by good comments. Unfortunately many people do not do this . . .

Comment: I agree. And I have been doing a lot of version 1 lately, I'll take your example and switch to version 2 whenever I can.